# How to hold an order right after the payment was received

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2.6

We have orders that have to be approved by another party after ordering and receiving the payment.

So I want to set it onHold after payment and unHold it via an API call I have to implement as well.

This question is about the first part:

I tried to hook an `$order->hold()` into the event `sales_order_place_after`, but the order still switches to PROCESSING.

Also I saw that in the admin interface I cannot set an PROCESSING order to hold is not working:

I am getting

> No order(s) were put on hold.

**EDIT1**

Debugging: Setting to Processing is happening here:

`\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\State\RegisterCaptureNotificationCommand::execute`